# What happens when one connect 110V appliance to 220V supply? Is there any way to safely connect such appliance to a 220V supply without damage?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

What happens when one connect a 110V appliance to a 220V supply, and vice
versa? Please explain in detail.
**Is there any way to safely connect such an appliance to a
220V supply without causing any damage?**

Comment: It’s called a transformer.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @JonCuster In theory, yes. But in  practice I don't recall ever seeing a (safety certified) transformer that plugs into a 240 vac or 120 vac receptacle outlet and supplies a 120 vac or 240 vac output receptacle for a cord and plug connected appliance. Most plug in transformers provide a low voltage output for electronic devices, charging cell phones, etc. But I suppose there could be some.

Comment: @BobD - I lived for a while in the Netherlands, with 240VAC plugs. The nearby Air Force base hosted a US squadron. At the Elektronika Dump (random electronics store) in my neighborhood it was easy to find nice 240->120 stepdown transformers for USAF personnel to buy to use their US appliances in the Netherlands. I bought one as I was moving back to the US since I had a nice stereo system I bought in Europe. After swapping out plugs for sockets and vice versa, I ran my 240V stereooff 120V in the US for several decades.

Comment: @BobD - 2kW step up/down transformer is ~$200 at Grainger. (Less on Amazon, but I wouldn't want to burn down my house).

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, but I should think these are low power (electronic product) applications. I doubt they are used for motor operated and heating appliances which can involve substantial power and which were the focus of my answer. You would need a pretty hefty transformer.

Comment: @BobD - 2kW is most of a 20A 120VAC circuit, standard in your house would be a 15A circuit which it covers. Yes, an oven or dryer wants more, but they aren't 120VAC in the first place. Plus from a good source they are UL or other NRTL listed so you are fine on safety.

Comment: @JonCuster Is this the transformer you are talking about/ https://www.amazon.com/Step-Up-Down-Voltage-Converter/dp/B01M1PLXYY#descriptionAndDetails 

Because it looks odd. Says it weighs 0.01 ounces(???).  I found a 100 VA version that weighs about 4 pounds.  What would the 2 KVA version weigh. Why would a US consumer would buy this thing? Would they drag it with them visiting other countries?Also, says it's "Granger approved". I see nothing about UL listed/certified.

Comment: @BobD - If you prefer, browse McMaster-Carr - easier to see what is UL listed. Of course, transformers are heavy. Not sure if anybody does an AC-DC-AC converter these days.

Comment: @JonCuster Having worked for UL for over 40 years I can tell you the only "proof" of UL listing is the mark on the product. I'm not saying that this manufacturer is doing so, but many times a claim of "UL approval" may only refer to the power cord, or to the transformer contained in the product, but not the complete product itself.

Comment: @BobD - understood fully since I sit on my corporate electrical safety committee. But, it is hard to suggest that transformers are dangerous given (1) the number of transformers your household electricity goes through to get to you, and (2) the number of large power transformers that used to be in all kinds of household and industrial equipment before cheap and effective DC-DC converters became common. And your 40 years at UL goes back to before that happened. I remember how much power supplies used to weigh...

Comment: @Jon Custer just to be clear, I never suggested transformers are dangerous. Appliance product safety depends upon the suitability of all the individual components for the application and, if not more, on the proper use of the product by the consumer, I’ll leave it at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double the supply voltage, you double the current which flows through the device. Any component of the appliance that is rated to carry a certain amount of current now has to carry twice that rating and it will dissipate four times as much power as it ordinarily would, and its insulation will scorch or catch fire.

Also, any component which is voltage-sensitive (microprocessors, solid state relays, LED's, etc.) will be subjected to twice its rating and the semiconductor junctions inside it will fail.

The only safe way to run a 110VAC device on 220VAC is with a *step-down transformer* as pointed out by Jon Custer.

Comment: I agree with all arguments, but the bad thing is, it will not ge twice as hot, since the energy produced is 4 times, it goes with the square of the voltage,

Comment: @trulia, I will correct this, thanks.

Comment: Regarding 240 to 120 vac step down transformers, in practice I don't recall ever seeing a (safety certified) transformer that plugs into a 240 vac receptacle outlet and is provided with a 120 vac output receptacle for connecting a cord and plug connected appliance. Most plug in transformers provide a low voltage output for electronic devices, charging cell phones, etc. But I suppose there could be some.

Comment: @BobD, these things do exist and are used by people who travel a lot and need to run appliances and household stuff on two different voltages. Large versions are used industrially to run production equipment where the mains voltages don't match up.

Comment: Are you talking about adapters which are used for dual voltage rated appliances? I'm obviously aware of those but they're not transformers. But can you give me any links to transformers for household appliances? (Not industrial applications, since the OP is only asking about appliances). If they do exist, I find it hard to believe they would be for anything other than low power stuff.

Comment: No, I am talking about actual transformers- I used them during a 6-month posting to Singapore, having inherited them from the previous team upon their departure. They were definitely iron-core transformers weighing many pounds and capable of ~1000 watts in operation.

Answer (score 2):

What happens will depend on the type of appliance and its components. That includes damage to the appliance as well as an increased risk of fire, electric shock, and personal injury.

Bottom line: Always connect an appliance to a voltage source as per the rating of the appliance by the manufacturer.

ps. My comments are based on 40+ years experience in testing, evaluating and developing safety standards for electrical appliances.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Bottom line**: don't do it.

If there is a rating, it is (usually) there for a reason.

Having said that, as Bob D, said, it will depend on the type of the appliance. Almost all electronic appliances will encounter problems sooner or later. Either not functioning properly (which is the best case scenario), or starting fires.

The only way to avoid this type of problems is through a transformer, but even there are cases that you might have to pay attention to the frequency of the grid (60Hz or 50Hz).